# Aqua Data studio, compare results, column names case-sensitive

Tags: case-insensitive, aquafold

Any Aqua Data studio users out here know how to turn off case-sensitivity when comparing results?

e.g. in one Query, column 1 is called "test", in another one it's called "TEST", then Aqua datastudio does not identify these columns when comparing results. How can I turn this off?

I can ignore upper/ lower case in the result set, but not in the column names.

Renaming every column each time manually is a pain. Somebody knows?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Results Compare, cant you change your SQL Query to the same case, using Upper or using ALIAS for the column name ? I used for e.g. UPPER("category") AS CATEGORY and this solved the problem you are having.

[image]

For Schema Compare do the below 
Under File->Options, Compare, enable option to Ignore Case 
When you perform a Schema Compare, Under Object Alignment, you can select to Ignore Case

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this is still not exactly what I need. The first part of your answer addresses only the result set, but not the column headers actually. But I dont want to do a schema compare either. Please see the edit of my original post for an example image. Thanks.

Comment: I changed the sql using Upper and solved the problem. See new screenshot attached

Comment: Thanks. although it still needs manual adaption, this seems to be the best solution.